# what is the meaning of the line bboxes= utils.format_boxes(bboxes,height,weight)

Tags: python, yolov4

I'm trying for object tracking using webcam using yolov4. I want to know the meaning of this line -> bboxes = utils.format_boxes(bboxes, original_h, original_w). I'm using  https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort.git  repository for cloning. One can find the above line in object_tracer.py file. - line 151.

```
# format bounding boxes from normalized ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax ---> xmin, ymin, width, height
        original_h, original_w, _ = frame.shape
        bboxes = utils.format_boxes(bboxes, original_h, original_w)
```

Comment: the source is all there. just read it. -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is literally in the comment at the first line of the code you pasted.

This method translates bounding boxes in normalized coordinates `(xmin, ymin, xmax, y max)` to not normalized coordinates `(xmin, ymin, width, height)`.

Coordinates are usually expressed in pixels, which is the **not** normalized form. Normalized coordinates are ones that are divided by the image dimensions, i.e. numbers between 0 and 1.

The point `(xmin, ymin)` is the top-left corner of the bounding box and `(xmax, ymax)` the bottom-right one. `(width, height)` is simply the dimensio of the bounding box.